# How can add existing name used attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I want to change `attr('src', 'imagename')`.

But Preserving the existing name.

```
<image src="abc">
<jquery>
 $('image).attr('src','' )  -> abcde
 and just add existing abc + de
```

How can I solve this problem?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the actual element is `<img>` not `<image>`
2. Use the same code to get src first and then replace the value by adding an extra string to it.

Running example:

```js
$('img').attr('src', $('img').attr('src')+'de');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="abc">
```

Comment: This only works properly when there is only 1 `img` element.

Comment: @Ram yes, there is no such requirement given by the OP of changing multiple images src and concatenating the same letters in each.

Answer (score 1):

The element name is `img` not `image`. Here is one way of doing this:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(_, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + 'de';
});
```

Note that this affects all elements in the jQuery collection, i.e. this adds the `"de"` to all `img` elements' `src` attribute.